# About alias implementation in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, alias, implementation

I would like to ask about the methods of alias in **elastic search**, how are **addAlias** and **removeAlias** implemented? How do they avoid problems with **atomicity** among other operations? For example, how to ensure that the alias information is always **in the state at the beginning of the operation** when performing an operation? Because I'm not very familiar with the code, I can't find the corresponding code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the Elasticsearch class called [AliasAction](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/metadata/AliasAction.java) where add and remove alias functionality is implemented as part of  implementation of the above abstract class, for example addAlias is implemented as part of [Add](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/metadata/AliasAction.java#L69) class and similarly [remove](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/metadata/AliasAction.java#L159) action has its own class and logic.